# Using Grass v.transform rotation point?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I have used v.transform for affine transformation and it works OK in terms of rotating and scaling (I do one step at the time), however, it always displaces the shapefile.

For example, for the shapefile below I have rotation specified and the other values remain default. The output transformed is rotated as expected by is shifted geographically. It seems that it is rotation from (0,0) of the start of the coordinates.

[image: Rotation specified]

I could not find the place where to specify the point of rotation.

Comment: You should use more transformation in a sequence. First try to move the center of the rotation to the origin. Rotate around origin. Finally move back the origin (inverse transformation of first).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the rotation of `v.transform` is centered at coordinates (0, 0).

Not an answer and quite the contrary, may I suggest to ditch GRASS `v.transform` and start using SAGA `Transform vector layer` tool?

In QGIS, it is in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector general tools | Transform vector layer`.

Near the bottom of its window, you will find **X** and **Y** entry fields. These are the area we can set the anchor point (rotation center). So you will no longer need to adjust the feature after rotation.

The angle is measured in degrees, clockwise starting from North.

[image]